# understanding system call dup()?

Tags: dup

Wanted to know what happens to the global file table and inode table when I do  dup()

I know it returns an int, and it opens a new file descriptor in the file descriptor table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dup call does not alter the inode or any system table.
It only alters the file descriptor table which is a process related table.

I think these 2 questions might help you understand what dup actually does.
[Difference between creating a duplicate file descriptor using dup() and creating a hard link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337122/difference-between-creating-a-duplicate-file-descriptor-using-dup-and-creating)
[dup2 / dup - why would I need to duplicate a file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635219/dup2-dup-why-would-i-need-to-duplicate-a-file-descriptor)

Bottom-line : Dup doesn't affect the system in anyway , just the process.

Comment: so when u dup, wont it affect de descriptor table?

Comment: it does affect the descriptor table. But that table is only per process table. Each process when created is assigned various stuff by the OS ( a pid , a fd (file descriptor table) etc. in *nix systems). That's why creating a process always takes longer than creating a thread (the process creation overhead). Still dup won't affect inodes or other system data.